Having trouble showing isomorphism.
Let $q=2^a$ and we define define $H:=\{(x,y):x,y\in GF(q)\}$ where $GF(q)$ is the product of $a$ number of cyclic groups $C_2$. I am trying to prove that $H$ becomes a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4^a$ with the multiplication $(x,y)\oplus (w,z):=(x+w,y+z+xw)$.
I have shown that $H$ endowed with this operation is indeed a group but I am having trouble writing down the proof that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4^a$. Intuitively, for example let $a=3$, I would guess that the biejction we want to form is $((1,0,0),(1,0,0))$ to $(1,0,0)$, $((0,1,0),(0,1,0))$ to $(0,1,0)$ and $((0,0,1),(0,0,1))$ to $(0,0,1)$ so we have to show that $((1,0,0),(1,0,0)),((0,1,0),(0,1,0)),((0,0,1),(0,0,1))$ generates $H$ which makes sense but im not sure how to give a proper proof especially for the general case where $a$ can be any integer. Also, im not sure how to show that the homomorphism above is well-defined.
